# if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) loop does not execute - iOS

Tags: ios, database

below is my code to update records in database...

```
-(BOOL) addScoreInDatabase:(classname *)objGames
{
    BOOL success;
    sqlite3 *database;

    const char *dbpath = [self.databasePath UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        NSData *strJson = [objGames getJSON];

        NSString *strContent = [[[[NSString alloc]
                                  initWithData:strJson encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"null" withString:@"\"\""];
        NSLog(@"strcom %@",strContent);
        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE gamescore SET data ='%@' WHERE id = 1",strContent];
        NSLog(@"query %@",query); 
        const char *sqlStatement = [query UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, & statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                success = TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                success = FALSE;
            }
            sqlite3_exec(database, "VACUUM;", 0, 0, nil);
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    return success;
}
```

and it doesn't go inside **if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) loop**

and Resulted query is

```
UPDATE gamescore SET data ='{
  "title" : "pacman",
  "time" : "55",
  "score" : "200",
  "level" : "1"
}' WHERE id = 1
```

and when i execute this query in Sqlite Manager it doesn't update the records instead it shows something like this [image]

Can anybody help me to update my records ?!..Thanks !!

Comment: Shouldn't you be escaping those newlines?

Comment: which loop? i can't find any

Comment: Try insert data array into 1 line

Comment: Problem has been solved..Thanks for Concern !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqlite3_exec() method instead of sqlite3_step().

sqlite3_exec() will execute whatever the query you have given.

Try this out.

```
enter code 
-(BOOL) addScoreInDatabase:(classname *)objGames
{
BOOL success;
sqlite3 *database;

const char *dbpath = [self.databasePath UTF8String];

if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    NSData *strJson = [objGames getJSON];

    NSString *strContent = [[[[NSString alloc]
                              initWithData:strJson encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"null" withString:@"\"\""];
    NSLog(@"strcom %@",strContent);
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE gamescore SET data ='%@' WHERE id = 1",strContent];
    NSLog(@"query %@",query); 
    const char *sqlStatement = [query UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, & statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_exec(database, "VACUUM;", 0, 0, nil);
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
return success;
```

}